# Delphi XE memory leak in TWSDLLookup.Destroy method

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, hook

I am using Delphi XE. I have come across a memory leak problem using Delphi Soap. It turns out to be due to a missing .Free call in `TWSDLLookup.Destroy`, as described in [QC 91160](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=91160)

The problem that I have is the described work-around, which is simply to add `FLookup.Free` to the `TWSDLLookup.Destroy` method.
 I don't want to change the Delphi source, so I tried copying the unit to my project folder, making the change and recompiling, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533686/can-i-recompile-the-pas-files-used-by-the-delphi-ide) in Tom's answer. The problem with this technique is that it apparently only works if you also recompile all the dependent units. I have tried copying just `WSDLLookup.pas` to my project directory and I get a Stackoverflow error. I'm not familiar with Web Services / SOAP so I don't know what other units I should copy over if I do use this technique.

Rob Kennedy's answer on the same page describes a different technique involving code hooking - but it doesn't seem to apply to object methods. I have done as he suggests and downloaded the free code for the TNT Unicode controls and located the relevant procedures, but I have been unable to find info on how to hook an object's methods - if indeed this is possible. If I could do this, I would then hook `TWSDLLookup.Destroy` and add the `FLookup.Free` call.

Any ideas for how to fix this will be much appreciated. I'm a bit of a newbie programmer so I'm hoping that I've missed something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do does in fact work fine. I tested it out myself. Here's the project file I used:

```
program WSDLLookupTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  WSDLLookup in 'WSDLLookup.pas';

var
  intf: IInterface;

begin
  intf := GetWSDLLookup as IInterface;
end.
```

I made a copy of the `WSDLLookup.pas` file and placed it in the same directory as the .dpr file. Then, in the copy rather than the original, I modified `TWSDLLookup.Destroy`.

```
destructor TWSDLLookup.Destroy;
begin
  Beep;
  ClearWSDLLookup;
  FLookup.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

I added the `Beep` to prove to myself that this code was indeed being executed.

In your position I would definitely use this solution instead of attempting code hooks. And of course the other simple solution is to upgrade to a later Delphi version.

One thing to be careful of is to remember to remove the modified unit when you do upgrade. The leak was fixed in XE2.

Comment: I saw something about that maybe the use of debug dcus would cause a problem - possibly that's why I get my stack overflow. Or maybe I have another bug.

Comment: Anyway, thanks again. Since it does work, I'll try find out what else I'm doing wrong :)

Comment: @DavidOrpen No interaction with Debug DCUs.